# Share mercurial command server between multiple processes

Tags: php, mercurial, process, pipe

I'm using Mercurial to create repositories based on other repositories (i.e. merging them together). This is done by a nice little webinterface using PHP on the server.

Unfortunately, for some tasks this is extremely slow (no wonder, PHP currently has to exec() hg about 40 times per request). So I thought about using the command server, available in Mercurial 1.9+.

As far as the docs go, I can start a simple `hg serve` and let it work on multiple repositories (by giving each command the `-R` option). This is great. But can I also share the command server between mutliple (and maybe concurrent) requests?

I'm doing something like this to start the server from within my PHP script:

```
$cmd         = 'hg serve --cmdserver pipe';
$pipes       = null;
$descriptors = array(
   STDIN  => array('pipe', 'r'),
   STDOUT => array('pipe', 'w')
);

$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptors, $pipes);

if (!is_resource($process)) {
    throw new Exception('Could not start command server.');
}
```

But this makes the server only available to the current PHP process. Since I'm not familiar with using pipes and stuff, I now wonder: Is it possible to start the server once (outside PHP) and "connect" to it? Like opening a socket and reading/writing to it.

And if it's possible: Is it wise? What happens when multiple PHP processes start using the one server's socket/pipe/whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command server is **blocking** and will only serve one request at a time. There is currently (as of Mercurial 2.0) no way to connect to the server over a socket like you suggest, though it would certainly be interesting to have that functionality.

So you cannot use it to speed up different requests, but if a single request starts Mercurial 40 times, then there might already be a lot to gain from making those 40 requests go through the same command server.

If you're interested in talking to the command server from multiple (concurrent) clients, then I suggest you start a discussion about it at [Mercurial mailing list](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MailingLists).

Comment: It's a great question and I'm happy we can document it here for others  who wonder the same thing.